# How to hide parameter based on another parameter value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have 2 parameters `param1` and `param2`. `param1` has values true and false. My requirement is that if I select true in `param1` then `param2` should be hidden and if I select false in `param1` then `param2` should be visible. Can this be achieved in SSRS?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot change a parameter's visibility during run time. Alternatively, you can control the second parameter's values based on the selected value of the first parameter. Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481738/hide-parameter-dropdown-control-from-the-toolbar-in-ssrs-based-on-another-para

Comment: Ram, can you add this as the answer to the question please, instead of a comment? This helps other users identify unanswered questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide parameter (dropdown control from the toolbar) in SSRS based on another Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481738/hide-parameter-dropdown-control-from-the-toolbar-in-ssrs-based-on-another-para)

Answer (score 4):

As per Nathan's comment I am adding Amar's comment here as answer/partial answer

Unfortunately, you cannot change a parameter's visibility during run time. Alternatively, you can control the second parameter's values based on the selected value of the first parameter.

Check this post - [Hide parameter (dropdown control from the toolbar) in SSRS based on another Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481738/hide-parameter-dropdown-control-from-the-toolbar-in-ssrs-based-on-another-para)

Answer (score 2):

As Amar pointed out you cannot hide parameters dynamically, but what you can do is grey them out for single-value parameters, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691210/ssrs-grey-out-parameter-based-on-result-from-other-parameter).
For multi-value parameters that won't work, because multi-value parameters are not allowed to be null.

But instead you can modify your DataSet and the default value for the parameter. To limit the user's choice list.
Let me give you an example:

Let's say you have 2 parameters that are cascaded. So you want to choose something from the first parameter and depending on what you choose in the first parameter you get a different result in second parameter. ([Microsoft has a documentation about this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx))

Now we can use this cascading to set the values in the second parameter. So for instance if we choose the value `1` in the first parameter we want the second parameter act normal and show its data to choose from, but in any other case we want the second parameter to have limited data to choose from. And this what I'm going to show. You got a second parameter that looks like this:

[image: General information for second parameter]

In the `Available Values` we choose the DataSet with its values and labels for the second parameter. Which could look like this:

[image: Available Values for second parameter]

Now in the DataSet for the second parameter, here `DataSet1`, we need to specify when to show the limited data and when not:

[image: DataSet for second parameter]

So what we do is set one label `All` with the value `-1` when the value of the first parameter is not `1` else the DataSet returns all the data from the table/function/stored procedure/ etc.

Lastly the second parameter shall have the default value `-1` with the label `All` chosen when the first parameter is not `1`. So back to the second parameter properties. For `Default Values` the value `-1` needs to be specified:

[image: Default Values of the second parameter]

So now the user only gets the preselected `All` in the list to choose from when the first parameter is not `1`. Otherwise the full list will be provided. All that has to be done now is to declare what is done when the value of the second parameter is `-1`.