# How to hide parameter in ssrs after select true or false in another parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have a problem with my parameters.
I created boolean parameter with two options.True or False.
I want from parameter to do the following :
When i select true - > my another parameter (in my case parameter Date) becomes active.
When i select false - > my second parameter ( in my case parameter Date2) becomes active and the first parameter above becomes inactive.How can i do that?

I did this : 
=iif(Parameters!Choose.Value=true,Parameters!for_date.Value,false)
and 
=iif(Parameters!Choose.Value=true,1,0)
but with no result...

I expected when i select true - > the first parameter to becomes active
false -> another parameter becomes active and the first becomes inactive.

Comment: Possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246168/how-to-hide-parameter-based-on-another-parameter-value-in-ssrs

Comment: If you're comfortable injecting Javascript I can give you  an answer - @ me if this is the case.