# Show/Hide filter parameters based on condition with SSRS (.rdl) reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to hide the SSRS (.rdl) report parameter based on some condition.

Example:
Parameter-1
Forecast Type :
Value-1 :Monthly
Value-2 :Yearly
Parameter-2
Fiscal year

so  if the user select Forecast Type = Monthly then the fiscal year parameter should show otherwise it should hide

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not possible. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246168/how-to-hide-parameter-based-on-another-parameter-value-in-ssrs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide parameter based on another parameter value in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246168/how-to-hide-parameter-based-on-another-parameter-value-in-ssrs)